# Some properties about prime ideal under Galois extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, class-field-theory, galois-extensions, ramification

Assume $K$ is a number field, $L$ is a Galois field extension of $K$ with Galois group $G$, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a fixed prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$, where $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$. I am trying to prove the following properties about ramification:

1. In the following two cases, there are no intermediate fields and then $G$ is a cyclic group with prime order:

   (1) $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in each intermediate field but not in $L$;

   (2) Each intermediate field contains a unique prime lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ but not for $L$.
2. In the following two cases, $G$ has a unique smallest (non-trivial) normal subgroup $H$, hence the orders of $G$ and $H$ are prime power and prime respectively, $H$ is in the center of $G$:

   (1) $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in each intermediate field but ramified in $L$;

   (2) $\mathfrak{p}$ completely splits in each intermediate field but not in $L$.
3. $G$ is a cyclic group with prime power order if $\mathfrak{p}$ is inert in each intermediate field but not in $L$.

Notice every "intermediate field" we mentioned does not contain $K$ or $L$ themselves.

Any discussion about anyone of these properties will be helpful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be using stuffs mentioned in Marcus' Number Fields, Chapter 4. So it might be nice to read it before reading my proof.

---

For (1), let $P \subset \mathcal O_L$ be a prime lying over $\mathfrak p$. Suppose $K \subset L$ has intermediate fields. Now consider the inertia group $E = E(P|\mathfrak p)$ and the inertia field $L_E$. It is the largest subfield in which a ramification doesn't occur. As ramification occurs in each intermediate subfield we have that $L_E=L$ or $K$. However, the ramification is multiplicative, so there $e(P|\mathfrak p) \not = 1$. Thus $L_E=K$. However we also have:

$$e(P|\mathfrak p) = [L:L_E] = [L:K]$$

This implies that $\mathfrak p$ ramifies totally in $L$. Thus $K \subset L$ has not intermediate fields.

Similarly for (2), suppose $K \subset L$ has intermediate fields. Now consider the decomposition field $L_D$. It is the largest field in which there is only splitting of ideals. On the other side by the condition in each intermediate field there has to be a ramification or the inertial degree increases. Thus again $L_D = L$ or $K$. Once again, since both of these are multiplicative we must have that $L_D = K$. However, now $\mathfrak p$ splits into $[L_D:K] = 1$ ideals in $L$, a contradiction. Thus $K \subset L$ has not intermediate fields.

Finally, since the extension is Galois and it has no intermediate fields, we must have that $G$ has no nontrivial proper subgroups. The only such groups are the groups of prime order. (You can use Cauchy's Theorem to prove this claim).

---

For (1) of the second claim, consider the inertia field $L_E$. It is the largest subfield in which no ramification occurs. By the hypothesis it is an intermediate subfield, which contains every other proper subfield of $L$. Under Galois correspondence $E$ is a minimal subgroup of $G$ and is of order $[L:L_E]$. Note that it is the only subgroup of this order, as it is contained in all non-trivial subgroups of $G$. So it must be the unique smallest (non-trivial) subgroup of $G$.

For (2), you can use the same idea, as in the first claim. Consider the decomposition field $L_D$. As in (1) it must contain every other proper subfield of $L$. Hence $D$ is contained in every proepr subgroup of $G$, so it must be the unique smallest (non-trivial) subgroup of $G$.

However, we can derive more information for $H$, the smallest (non-trivial) subgroup of $G$. For example, $G$ must be a prime power group. Indeed, if $p$ and $q$ are two distinct prime divisors of $|G|$, by Cauchy's Theorem we have a subgroups of order $p$ and $q$. However, they don't have a common non-trivial subgroup, which contradicts the fact that the $H$ is contained in every proper subgroup of $G$. Thus $|G|=p^k$ and obviously $|H| = p$. Also $H \le Z(G)$, trivially.

---

For the third claim, consider the decomposition field $L_D$. It is the largest subfield in which $\mathfrak p$ splits completely. By the hypothesis and the fact that the inertia degree is multiplicative we must have that $L_D = K$. Also consider the inertia fields $L_E$. As in the second claim it must contain every proper subfield of $L$. Moreover, it can't be $L$, itself, as $\mathfrak p$ isn't inert in $L$, so it must ramify, since no splitting occurs, as $L_D=K$. So in the notation from the second claim $D=G$ and $E=H$.

Hence, $G/H = D/E$, which is a cyclic group. Now as $H \le Z(G)$, by the third isomorphism theorem, $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $D/E$ and in particular it is cyclic. Then, as in [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_of_Group_by_Center_Cyclic_implies_Abelian) we have that $G$ is abelian. Moreover, as in the second claim we have that $|G| = p^k$ and also it has a unique subgroup of order $p$. The last claim implies that $G$ is cyclic. Indeed, if $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p^{i_1}} \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^{i_n}}$ it has $n$ subgroups of order $p$.

Hence the proof.

Comment: I am really grateful for your answer! It indeed helps me a lot. Sorry for replying so late, since I was busy with other things a few days ago, also I read this answer carefully to make sure I understand all of it. 

So I have got everything except one: why cannot $L_D$ be $L$ in the third claim? I think we can't say because $L_D\subseteq L_E\subsetneq L$, since the proof of "$L_E\neq L$" uses the fact "$L_D=K$". 

Finally, thank you for helping me again. :)

Comment: @Zigzag1263 If L has no intermediate subfield, then it is possible to have $L=L_D$, however then the problem is trivial, as $G$ must be of prime order. On the other side if $L$ has an intermediate field, using the multiplicity of the inertia degree, we have that the inertia degree of $\mathfrak p$ in $L$ is greater than 1. Thus $L \not = L_D$, since in the latter only splitting of ideals occur. Hence $L_D = K$

Comment: Oh yes, no intermediate field implies $G$ is cyclic of prime order, I forgot it. Thanks.